# UPDATE my script in python with python socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, updates

Hello I would like to ask if is possible to update my app with a socket server like in other apps when there is an update so its downloading and updating the code without downloading the app again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question directly, "yes, it is possible".  Python is a general purpose language and can do that kind of thing readily enough.  the "how" will depend your app.